# jQuery if condition not working when screen is small (mobile)

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, responsive

i have a simple jquery condition which is simply checking a css value as shown below

```
if ($('.classname').css("width") < '60%')  {

$.lightbox($'#popupbox'), {});
$('.classname').css({
  'width': '66%'
}

}
```

This is fired as part of a larger javascript function, Easy peasy right?

It works perfectly fine when the screen size is larger than 1029px

However, anything less and it seems to not be able to "detect" that the condition is true  and it doesn't need to fire the popup, and will fire the popup over and over everytime the function is executed.

I had thought this was caused directly by the screen size,  but it shouldn't be,  because the css value is in %  and it is => 60% regardless of screen size.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Look for [@media rulre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) for this. The `'60%'` cannot be evvaluated anyway here... The needed has to be in pixels, since `.css("width")` returns the dimention the browser has evaluated to render..

Comment: Their is no applicable media rule if that's what you mean.  

I can't use media for this,  because the function is checking the position of an element (slider)  on the page  if the slider is less than 60% the popup needs to be shown. 

there are also multiple conditions/popups depending on what options are selected on the page.

Comment: make sure `.classname` element has the positive width value when you shrink the window.

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) is returning a *«a computed style property»*.

For a width, that is in pixels. That is the current rendered width.

if you want to check if an element's width is 60% (or less) of another, you'll have to do the math. Something like:

```
var inner_element_width = $('.inner').css("width");
var outer_element_width = $('.outer').css("width");

if (inner_element_width <= (outer_element_width * 0.6))  {
  // Do something
}
```